# What does [,some_par] mean in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Looking through documentation I sometimes see a list of parameters containing par_n[,par x].
For example:
str.center(width[, fillchar])

What does this mean?
Any attempts of looking for answers using google and in stackoverflow have not been successful.

Comment: It's a notation of optional argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It marks an optional parameter. You can call  `mystring.center(42)` as well as `mystring.center(42, ' ')`. The function’s documentation should hint how the behavior would differ.